# Sign in with new OWIN Identity API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin

Suppose that I have a web site that accept user by randomly. Rule is simple; random generator can tell user can sign in or not.

So how should I  use this code?

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

I don't have ApplicationUser, I don't have injected  DbContext, I don't have users (!) table.

Main question; Where is my simple authentication?

```
  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage ("I_am_a_User", Persist.Checked)
```

Answer (score 0):

code look like ugly but I solved...

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        List<Claim> _claims = new List<Claim>()
                                {
                                    new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
                                        Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
                                        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", "LOCAL AUTHORITY"),

                                    new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                                        "I_am_a_User", 
                                        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", "LOCAL AUTHORITY"),

                                    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider",
                                        "ASP.NET Identity", 
                                        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", "LOCAL AUTHORITY"),                                        
                                };
        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(_claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```